# Makecert certificates safe?

Tags: ssl-certificate, sslstream, makecert

I made an application, which communicates over the. net `SSLStream`,  and for developing I used `makecert.exe` to create a self signed ssl certificate. Now Ive read in some microsoft article, that makecert should be used for testing only. 
Now my question is: is the application safe with this cert, or which program can i make a safe and comparible cert?
Any help will be greatly appreciated
**Edit: The self signed Certificate is hardcoded into the client application and it compares it everytime it establish a connection, so man-in-the-middle attack couldnt work, but how random are the makecert Certificates?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using **OpenSSL** to create a self-signed certificate used for production environment. I've never made thoughts about makecert.exe. To be honest: *You want to achieve an encrypted transfer* of your data using SSL *between* your Application and the server.

The hole certificate wont be displayed to the "user/customer". The only reason nowadays is to embedd a badge with "*this is a secure page*" to the page on which SSL is enabled.

If you are looking for this, you will definitely need a signed Certificate from a CA. If you are thinking about this, i recommend **StartSSL**, because it's far the cheapest and offers you for one time validation nearly unlimited wildcard certificates. Its trusted by microsoft and you can create a code-signing-cerficiate **for free**. (Onetime fee for validation only).

### Concerning the randomness and security of the certificate:

If you are validating the fingerprint of the certificate you are connecting to, there should be less security concerns. (i.e. Fiddler won't work this way).

SSL is based on [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) Algorithm so when generating a private/public keypair with a keysize of 2048 or even 4096 (max. on StartSSL) there shouldn't be any security concerns. How to create the Certificate you will find [here](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/linux/centos/openssl/self_signed_certificates/index.php)  If you wont trust RSA, you shoudn't trust anyone ;)

Keep in mind that most universities using self signed certificates created using OpenSSL. Its now [FIPS certificated](http://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/SecurityPolicy-2.0.pdf) and allowes you a wide bunch of settings to achieve fit your system.

Comment: Ty that was the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

It's safe if you find some secure way to get the certificate to everyone who uses your application. Otherwise, they'll have no way to know they're really talking to your application. Anyone else can run `makecert` just like you did, and nobody will have any way to know whether they're really talking to you. A certificate issued by a CA bind your identity to a certificate, allowing clients to know they're really talking to the right service.

When you punch `https://www.amazon.com` into your browser, how do you know you're sending your credit card information to Amazon and not an imposter? Well, Amazon has a certificate that was issued for `www.amazon.com` by a certification authority. An imposter could not get such a certificate -- the authority wouldn't issue it.

But if Amazon used a self-signed certificate ... well, anyone can do that. So how would I know I was actually talking to Amazon? I would have to know ahead of time which self-signed certificate that claimed to be for `www.amazon.com` was the right one. I wouldn't have a CA's stamp of approval to tell me.

Comment: Thank you, I already had solved the problem with the self signed cetificate by hard coding it into the client application.  But can you confirm that makecert certificates are random enough(there was an openssl bug e.g.,  where certs were not random enough, many private keys were leaked)

Answer (score 1):

you hardcoded your password (as a long cert) into your application, and you are asking if it's safe?

all I need is a copy of your code or wherever you stored it and I can hack all the apps you ever write. plus you cannot update or change it.

Answer (score 0):

Self-signed certificates say essentially "I certify that I am I. Signed: I". Look up how to set up you own certificate authority (it depends on your choosen environment, and there are several options). Use that authority to issue certificates, and set the servers and clients to trust your CA. No need to pay $$$$ for them, plus *you* know exactly under what conditions you hand out certificates.

Comment: Of course, but are makecert certificates random enough? (there was an openssl bug e.g., where certs were not random enough, many private keys were leaked, because it generated only 2000-3000 different keys)

Comment: @Tearsdontfalls, that is impossible to answer without a _detailed_ audit.